# Is there a way to update the value of variable inside a dynamic library (in real time)?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a dynamic shared library built that contains a simple struct with variables inside of it. My main program is in C++ and this program changes the values of the struct in real-time.

I want a python script to make use of the updated values in real-time.

However, the current python script (using ctypes) does not get the updated values.

Is there a way to make this happen? Is it possible to do so?

Current python looks like this (**script.py**):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import ctypes

# pulls library made from c++
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsharedObject.so')

# init constructor
lib.object_new.argtypes = []
lib.object_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p


# init do_something function
lib.object_do_something.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
lib.object_do_something.restype = ctypes.c_float

class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.object_new()
        print("`Object` instance (as a `void *`): 0x{:016X}".format(self.obj))

    def do_something(self):
        return lib.object_do_something(self.obj)


def main():
    print("Testing Library...")
    obj = Object()
    ret = obj.do_something()
    print(ret)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

shared library file (**sharedObject.h**):

```
// Data Structure for Raspberry Pi 
struct UAVTlm_t { 
    float       distance;      // distance
    UAVTlm_t(){
        distance = 7.12;
    }

    float do_something();

};
```

**sharedObject.cpp**

```
#include "sharedObject.h"    
struct UAVTlm_t;

float UAVTlm_t::do_something() {
    return distance;
}

extern "C" {
    UAVTlm_t *object_new(){
        return new UAVTlm_t;
    }

    float object_do_something(UAVTlm_t *pObj) { 
        return pObj->do_something(); 
    }
}
```

The library is built with the following line:

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -o libsharedObject.so sharedObject.cpp -lstdc++
```

Comment: Please post the sources of `the current python script`. Please post an [MCVE]

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You seem to be asking how to read memory of another process. It's possible in principle, but it's not as simple as loading a shared library that the other process also uses: each process gets its own copy of the data used by the library, even if they may share the code.

Comment: makes sense, is there a link to an example that I may be able to read into? Or another approach to this problem? Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cool sources! So: 1. What does the execution of _script.py_ output? 2. What do you want or expect _script.py_ to output? 3. Where is `suus_dist_takeoff` defined? Instead of `suus_dist_takeoff` you meant `distance` and you want it to print `7.12` from `print(ret)` in python? Doesn't it print that?

Comment: Some of the variables name need to be changed. But the python script does return 7.12. However, I am not sure how the value of it can be updated on real time.

Comment: So just add a function to `sharedObject.cpp` that will set `distance` to a new value?